# segment control + navigation bar in objective c

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I am new to i-phone development and right now working in an application where i need to use the segment control within a navigation based application. I have a segment control with two indexes,on clicking on each,the table view should be loaded with different data.

My problem is that even after initializing the segment control and also after setting the property and synthesizing,it is not displaying the segment control in my connection window,and hence i cant set the connection of the same with segment controller.

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
@synthesize segmentedControl
```

Can anybody guide me,where i am making a mistake? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

Comment: Thanks a lot Sherry,I don't know how i made such a silly mistake.Thanks again.